# If I know the PID number of a process, how can I get its name?

Tags: linux, unix, shell, process, pid

If I have the PID number for a process (on a UNIX machine), how can I find out the name of its associated process?

What do I have to do?

Comment: You can use `ps` or `ls -l /proc/$PID/exe`

Comment: @Eddy_Em that'll give you the executable file, which isn't always the process name. Also, that's not portable...

Comment: `ps -fp PID` will show full command

Comment: `readlink /proc/$PID/exe`

Answer (score 395, accepted):

On all POSIX-compliant systems, and with Linux, you can use `ps`:

```
ps -p 1337 -o comm=
```

Here, the process is selected by its PID with `-p`. The `-o` option specifies the output format, `comm` meaning the command name.

For the full command, not just the name of the program, use:

```
ps -p 1337 -o command
```

See also: [`ps` – The Open Group Base Specifications Issue 6](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696799/utilities/ps.html)

Comment: comm seems to truncate the command to 15 characters. Using `command` instead fixes it.

Comment: [Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS]

`$ ps -p 1 -o comm=`

init

`$ ps -p 1 -o command=`

/sbin/init; which means it is not about 15 characters, maybe just the binary's name vs. its full path.

Comment: Actually, `comm` gives the binary's name and `command` returns argument 0

Answer (score 64):

You can find the process name or the command used by the process-id or pid from

```
/proc/<pid>/cmdline
```

by doing

```
cat /proc/<pid>/cmdline
```

Here pid is the pid for which you want to find the name
For example:

```
 # ps aux

   ................
   ................
   user  2480  0.0  1.2 119100 12728 pts/0  Sl   22:42   0:01 gnome-terminal
   ................
   ................
```

To find the process name used by pid 2480 you use can

```
# cat /proc/2480/cmdline 

 gnome-terminal
```

Comment: Be careful: The OP mentions UNIX. Not all UNIXes implement the Plan 9 like process-specific file. Your answer generally only applies to Linux.

Comment: Whilst that's true, they did tag the question "linux". Anyone who is using a non-Linux based UNIX OS will be quite used to having to modify answers to fit their needs

Answer (score 20):

To get the path of of the program using a certain pid you can use:

```
ps ax|egrep "^ [PID]"
```

[image]

alternatively you can use:

```
ps -a [PID]
```

Or also:

```
readlink /proc/[PID]/exe
```

Comment: `ps -a` list all the processes that is associated with the terminal, it doesn't take any input.

Comment: @MichaelLee I guess it depenends on the `ps` version, on `procps version 3.2.7` works fine.

Answer (score 14):

You can use pmap.
I am searching for PID 6649. And cutting off the extra process details.

```
$ pmap 6649 | head -1
6649:   /usr/lib64/firefox/firefox
```

Comment: This command helped me more than I needed,  I have the full line of the process that started. Given a Java process, with the `ps` command all you'll see is just `java`, but the rest of parameters passed will be displayed fully with `pmap`.

Answer (score 9):

```
# ls -la /proc/ID_GOES_HERE/exe
```

Example:

```
# ls -la /proc/1374/exe
lrwxrwxrwx 1 chmm chmm 0 Mai  5 20:46 /proc/1374/exe -> /usr/bin/telegram-desktop
```

Comment: This one is perfect.

Comment: Probably better: `readlink /proc/1337/exe`. readlink - print resolved symbolic links or canonical file names.

Comment: Some one commented on the question that the executable name is not always the process name, e.g. gunicorn or nginx. Some processes will change it at runtime with `setprocname`

Comment: However if I want the executable name, this `/proc` way is perfect.

Answer (score 4):

You can Also use awk in combination with ps

```
ps aux | awk '$2 == PID number for a process  { print $0 }'
```

example:

```
root@cprogrammer:~# ps aux | awk '$2 == 1 { print $0 }'
root         1  0.0  0.2  24476  2436 ?        Ss   15:38   0:01 /sbin/init
```

to print HEAD LINE you can use

```
 ps --headers aux |head -n 1 && ps aux | awk '$2 == 1 { print $0 }'

                 (or) 

 ps --headers aux |head -n 1; ps aux | awk '$2 == 1 { print $0 }'


root@cprogrammer:~# ps --headers aux |head -n 1 && ps aux | awk '$2 == 1 { print $0 }'
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         1  0.0  0.2  24476  2436 ?        Ss   15:38   0:01 /sbin/init
```

Comment: This is unstable since it'd also select processes that happen to include the number anywhere in their command. Try `ps ax | grep 1` and see whether it really returns the `init` process, for example. (In my case, it returns 119 lines—not desirable.)

Comment: @slhck Modified the answer... thanks for info..  **ps -p 1 -o comm=** is best option for this question.

Comment: We don't need two runs to retain headers, instead use `ps aux | awk 'NR==1 || $2==PID'` -- and don't need to say `{print $0}` because it's the default. But as you commented, `-p` is better anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Simmilar to [slhck's Answer](https://superuser.com/a/632987/309066), but relying on file operations instead of command invocations:

```
MYPID=1
cat "/proc/$MYPID/comm"
```

Comment: [Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS] `cat /proc/1/comm` => init, not /sbin/init. His answer has the longer version included. But +1 anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Surprisingly, no one has mentioned the -f (full command) option for ps. I like to use it with -e (everything) and pipe the results to grep so I can narrow my search.

```
ps -ef | grep <PID>
```

This is also very useful for looking at full commands that someone is running that are taking a lot of resources on your system. This will show you the options and arguments passed to the command.

Comment: Doesn't work on BSD (maybe including MacOSX? I'm not sure). Even where `-e -f` are available, `grep` can produce many false matches e.g. `grep 33` includes pid=933 or 339, ppid=33 or 933 or 339, timeused of 33 seconds or 33 minutes, or programname or argument containing 33 -- including the `grep` itself. All (AFAIK) `ps` do have `-p`, so just `ps -fp 33`.

Answer (score 0):

I find the easiest method to be with the following command:

```
ps -awxs | grep pid
```

Comment: Apart from being highly inefficient compared to `ps -p${pid}`, this will pick up plenty of false positives - including the `grep` itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the path of the process by PID. You can use the `pwdx` command. The `pwdx` command reports the full path of the PID process.

```
$ pwdx 13896
13896: /home/user/python_program
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63447358/6077264

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this command:

```
cat /proc/PID/comm
```

It also works without root.

Comment: same answer was given 9 years ago !